# Set progressive view for multiple Alamofire calls in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In one Viewcontrollers, I have three Alamofire API calls...I wish to set progressive view's progress to 100% when the three API calls are completed?

PS: Also, can someone teach me how to do it for a single Alamofire API call too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Alamofire` offering progress block for giving status about api progress status, you can use this to show your progress of you request or response like below for single api,

```
 Alamofire.request("url", method: "httpMethod", parameters: "parameter", encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: "headers").downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

    // Progress block called frequently during the lifecycle of api.
    let fractionCompletedINpercentage = progress?.fractionCompleted * 100 

    }).validate().responseData(completionHandler: { (response) in

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            // Download success
        } else if response.result.isFailure {
            // Download failed
        }

    })
```

For handling multiple api, you can use `Bool` for each api and show your progress by taking minimum or average of fraction completed from all api progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The download progress is available right in the Alamofire's doc

```
let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)

Alamofire.download("https://httpbin.org/image/png")
.downloadProgress(queue: utilityQueue) { progress in
    print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
.responseData { response in
    if let data = response.result.value {
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

That said, it probably wouldn't work if the API response is gzipped or the content-length header isn't set.

Answer (score -1):

Working method to use Alamofire

```
    let strURL:String = "https://xxxx"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["keyword": "current_timestamp"]

    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response.data!)
                    print(response.result)

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer, but not related to his question. He asked progress handling for single api.